# Deriving an expression - Set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm having trouble figuring out how to derive the right side of the following expression:

[image]

This is what I thought would work:

P(A' ∩ B' ∩ C) = P (C) − P (A ∩ B ∩ C)

However it's incorrect.

Would appreciate it if anyone can refer me to a specific axiom or axioms that were used in the process of deriving the expression on the right, or alternatively show me step by step how it was derived, please.

Comment: $P(X^c\cap Y)=P(Y)-P(X\cap Y)$ is used twice.

Comment: Meaning, P(A' ∩ B' ∩ C) = P (C) − P (C ∩ B) + P (C) − P (C ∩ A)? @Berci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the hint given by Berci, which is $P(X'\cap Y)=P(Y)-P(X\cap Y)$.

\begin{align}
&P(A'\cap B' \cap C)\\
&= P(A'\cap (B'\cap C)) \quad (\text{take } X=A', Y=B'\cap C)\\
&=P(B'\cap C)-P(A\cap B'\cap C)\\
&=P(C)-P(B\cap C)-P(A\cap B'\cap C) \quad(\text{take } X=B, Y=C)
\end{align}